# Checking uniform integrability of random series

Tags: probability-theory, solution-verification, random-variables, probability-limit-theorems, uniform-integrability

> Let $(X_n)_{n\geq 1}$ be a sequence of iid random variables such that $\mathbb{E}[X_n]=0$ and $\operatorname{\mathbb{V}ar}[X_n]=\sigma^2<\infty$, define $$ Y_n = \frac{X_1+\dots+X_n}{\sqrt{n}}$$
> and show that $\{Y_n; n\geq1\}$ is uniformly integrable colection.

My question is related to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1843680/showing-uniform-integrability-of-random-variables), main answer points that the following strategy is a valid proof, however there aren't any details, so I would like to check if the following proof I wrote is indeed correct.

Notice that

\begin{align}
\sup_{n\geq1} \mathbb{E}[|Y_n|^2] &= \sup_{n\geq1} [|(X_1+\dots+X_n)n^{-1/2}|^2]\\
&= \sup_{n\geq1} n^{-1}\mathbb{E}[|(X_1+\dots+X_n)|^2] \\
&=\sup_{n\geq1} n^{-1}\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 + 2\sum_{1\leq k < j \leq n}X_kX_j\right] \\
&=\sup_{n\geq1} n^{-1}\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2\right] \\
&=\sup_{n\geq1} n^{-1} n\sigma^2 \\&
= \sigma^2 <\infty
\end{align}
and as we know that $\varphi:x\to|x|^2$ is a test function for UI as $\lim_{x\to+\infty}\phi(x)/x=+\infty$, it follows that $\sup_{n\geq 1}\mathbb{E}[\varphi(|X_n|)] = \sigma^2 <\infty$ for all $n\geq1$ implies that $\{Y_n;n\geq 1\}$ is uniformly integrable.

Comment: I think that there is a result that states that if $X_n$ is a sequence bounded in $\mathscr{L}^{1+r}$ for some $r > 0$ then $X_n$ is u.i. Note that you are just (ver complicatedly) using the basic fact that $\mathbf{Var}(a\sum_i X_i+b) = a^2 \sum_i \mathbf{Var}(X_i)$ for independent random variables $(X_i).$

Comment: By the way, the proof is correct.

Comment: "there aren't any details": I did not give the detail that $EY_n^2= EX_1^2$ because the opening poster in the other post figured it out. Your proof is correct.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo I understand, I didn't mean in a bad way. Sometimes a tip is sufficient. Thanks for proof-checking btw.

Comment: @BelwarDissengulp I did not take it badly :) Just that in the context of the previous answer it was not needed to give more details. And the point of your question was to give all the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof that $\mathbb E\left[Y_n\right]$ can be bounded independently of $n$ and that a sequence which is bounded in $\mathbb L^2$ is uniformly integrable is correct.